# Passing unconsumed fling from parent to child

Tags: android

In short i'm using [NestedScrollingChild2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild2) and [NestedScrollingParent2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingParent2) to delegate part of unconsumed scroll + fling from child to parent.
I need backward behavior too, i.e. delegate unconsumed fling from parent to child. Seems like mentioned above classes doesn't cover this case.
The questions is:

1. How to track when parent's fling reach end of parent's content.
2. How to interrupt fling of parent.
3. How to delegate fling to children. Thinking about RecyclerView.fling(int, int)